# I have to make a split function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

Edit
sorry if the question wasn't clear
here is the question..

create your version of javascript split function, 
you may use indexOf and substring to help. 
so if i give you a string "heellloolllloolllo" and i want to remove "llll" the function should return "heellloooolllo"

This what I did so far:

```
function split() {

    var entered_string  = document.forms["form1"]["str"].value;
    var deleted_char = document.forms["form1"]["char"].value;
    var index = entered_string.indexOf(deleted_char);
    var i = deleted_char.length;
    var result;
    var x ;
    for (x = 0; x< entered_string.length; x++ )
    {
        if (index < 0) {
            result = entered_string;
        } else {
            result = entered_string.substring(0, index) +entered_string.substring(index+i);
        }
    }
    alert(result)
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: do you want a split function or a find and delete function?

Comment: Why wouldn’t you just use `String#replace`?

Comment: So you found 4 `llll` and `replace` them with nothing. ?

Comment: @Xufox  the question itself is clear, but it's asking for debugging, which is, as we know, off topic (we know this because the [ask] page says so) (I wrote the comment like this because the asker should go read that page)

Comment: @ItamarG3 The question is _not_ clear. The post reads _“These are my requirements and this is my code”_. There _is no question_ to be answered here. Asking for debugging help itself isn’t off-topic, if it doesn’t lack an actual _specific problem statement_.

Comment: If you want to split a string with    `4 l's`, you can directly use the javascript's     `split()` function and then concatenate the array.

Comment: sorry if the question wasn't clear here is the question 
create your version of javascript split function, 
you may use indexOf and substring to help. 
so if i give you a string "heellloolllloolllo" and i want to remove "llll" the function should return "heellloooolllo"

Comment: @AhmadBinMohammad: answer updated. Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Use the [`replace()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function with the `g` at the end of your regular expression. It's called a "global modifier".

```js
var string = 'heellloolllloolllo';

var res = string.replace(/llll/g, '');

console.log(res)
```

If your substring is a variable then you need to construct a new Regex object and set the `g` as the second parameter.

```js
var string = 'heellloolllloolllo';
var find = 'llll';

var regex = new RegExp(find,'g');
var res = string.replace(regex, '');

console.log(res)
```

There are other useful modifiers you can use:

- g - Global replace. Replace all instances of the matched string in the provided text.
- i - Case insensitive replace. Replace all instances of the matched string, ignoring differences in case.
- m - Multi-line replace. The regular expression should be tested for matches over multiple lines.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207227/6331369) for more information, credit to @codejoe.

Comment: But the substring is a variable

Answer (score -1):

Using [String#replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) (the clean way)

```js
var str = 'llllheellloolllloolllollll';
var matchStr = 'llll';

function removeSubString(str, matchStr) {
  var re = new RegExp(matchStr, 'g');
  return str.replace(re,"");
}

console.log(removeSubString(str, matchStr));
```

Using [String#indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [String#substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

```js
var str = 'llllheellloolllloolllollll';
var matchStr = 'llll';

function removeSubString(str, matchStr) {
 var index = str.indexOf(matchStr);
 while(index != -1) {
  var firstSubStr = str.substring(0, index);
  var lastSubStr = str.substring(index + matchStr.length);
  str = firstSubStr + lastSubStr;
  index = str.indexOf(matchStr);
 }
 return str;
}

console.log(removeSubString(str,matchStr))
```

Comment: OP can't manually build that pattern when it is variable based on user input