# Replace all occurrences of a string from a text file for a list of names

Tags: javascript, typescript, string, text

I have some typescript code that reads 5 players from a text file. The problem is I am unable to remove the word "player - " from all of them?

Example of the text file:

```
player - toby
player - coby
player - roby
player - poby
player - boby
```

Here is the code I wrote:

```
  const players = fs
    .readFileSync(`${__dirname}/db/players.txt`, {
      encoding: 'utf8',
      flag: 'r',
    })
    .toString().replace('player - ',"")
    .split('\n');
```

but it only is replacing for one person?

Comment: Along with regex as written in answer by @lucumt, you can use [replace.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with regex to do it

```
.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/db/players.txt`, {
  encoding: 'utf8',
  flag: 'r',
})
.toString().replace(/player - /g,"")
.split('\n');
```

[**TS Oline Demo**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBHSOMScACiqwYiAWkAAao4KAxpO5QABeUAAIgWTG%20s3Q0jw80YeCF5WBovFgux5TYot5ijMtPpjJZlHZnJ5arpDPcWrZHMgAScAosAApgALJQrQMBmLxebyAJQAbkUCE4gng7gC0HgzCt%20o1RtZOsgbqAA)

Comment: THIS WORKED PERFECTLY. Is there a particular reason this worked and not the previous method? or can you link me to something that explains the difference

Comment: @SOCESC Maybe you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206911/why-do-i-need-to-add-g-when-using-string-replace-in-javascript

Comment: Ah, global modifier i see. ur the best thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use split method. Your item will be two items of array. You need to get second part.

```
const data = ["player - toby", "player - coby","player - roby","player - poby","player - boby"]
  
const newData = data.map(item=> item.split(" - ")[1])
console.log(newData)
```